# How to starfile with program which I want?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example: you want to start file "hello.txt" in python, you will use this code:

`os.startfile("hello.txt)`

But the system will open "hello.txt" with default program

If I want to start "hello.txt" with Sublime Text or notepad+ or any program which is not a default program. What I have to do:?:(

Thanks (and sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions: Distribute the editor within you application or search for it on the local file system. Most editors got CLI commands, mostly just append the filename right next to the editors executable in command line.

Comment: can you give me a example of seccond solutions?